# How to use OnTouchEvent Correctly?

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, touch-event, ontouch

How would I use the `OnTouchEvent` function to make an `ImageView` move to the right or left when the user touches the right or left of the screen? The following code is what I have tried. What could I do to improve this and make it work?

```
ImageView circle1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.circle1);

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent MotionEvent motionEvent;
        motionEvent){

    switch (motionEvent.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

        // Player has touched the screen
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            if (motionEvent.getY() > screenHeight - screenWidth / 8) {
                circleIsMovingRIGHT = true;
                circleIsMovingLEFT = false;
            } else {
                circleIsMovingRIGHT = false;
                circleIsMovingLEFT = true;
            }
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
 @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

          anyView.setOnTouchListener(this);
       }


 @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.anyView:
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    // perform here
                }
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

add this code in res/anim/rotate.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rotate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:duration="1200" 
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"/>
```

Add This code at "//perform here" for rotate view (Component)

```
imageView.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,R.anim.rotate));
```

if you are use android:repeatCount="infinite" then you will stop the rotation dynamically, apply this code on specific condition

```
imageView.clearAnimation();
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! Last question, how would I make the image move? What code would I put where the   //perform here   comment is?

Comment: what you actual perform there, please tell me in detail .

you mean, when user click on ImageView then it is rotate at there.

Comment: What I wanted to perform is, that, when the User touches the Left or Right part of their device's screen, the image moves accordingly to the Left or Right.

Comment: So, you use the FrameLayout and set ImageView , linearlayout set weightsum is 1,orientation horizontal , and this layout within set other two layout and set weight_layout 0.5 and when you click on left of layout then show position of image - 1 and when you click on right side of layout then set the image position is +1..  i hope this ex. is help of you.